# What'd I do Wrong With My Textures (2.80)

Tags: modeling

**I solved the problem by just re-creating the texture with new graphics and stuff. Whatever I did, I wasn't able to undo it.**

[image][image][image]I'm working on a model and my texture comes out as stripes instead of the image texture it's supposed to be. I had it looking right a little while ago--but I screwed something up and I can't figure out what. I built this with 2.80.

The texture is on the front panel--body stain--I'm trying to give the ship a brushed steel texture and then put some damage / distressed metal textures on it where I want them to be.

This is the link to the .blend (too big to upload directly). https://www.dropbox.com/s/n2jtj2s1wo47sc2/cutter2.blend?dl=0

NOTE: I have UV Unwrapped the model. Also--something appears to be wrong with the texture itself. see the image I just added at the top.

Comment: did you unwrap or not your model? that could be the problem..

Comment: I did unwrap it--and tried the smart-wrap option as well.